# Hypercohomology of topological abelian groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, topological-groups, etale-cohomology

Suppose $X$ is a scheme, and $A, B$ two étale sheaves of locally compact **topological** abelian groups. Assume there is a map of étale sheaves such that for any $f: U\to X$ étale, $\Gamma(U_{\rm ét}, A)\to \Gamma(U_{\rm ét}, B)$ is continuous with discrete image.

Can the higher cohomology groups be topologized with locally compact topologies such that $H^j(X_{\rm ét}, A)\to H^j(X_{\rm ét}, B)$ is continuous with discrete image?

In other words, if this is possible for $j=0$ on all objects of the small étale site of $X$, is it possible for all $j$?

Comment: You can put the discrete topology on $H^j(X_{\text{ét}},-)$. I somehow imagine this is not what you want...